# Is OkHttp equivalent code really OK in Postman?

Tags: android, postman, okhttp

I'm trying to send a `json` post request to some API which in response sends a binary file back.

I'm doing well in `Postman`:

Header:

[image: Headers]

Body and result:

[image]

And I get the following code from `Code` section in `Postman` for `Java/OKHTTP`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\r\n  \"Text\":\"Hello\",\r\n  \"APIKey\":\"MY_API_KEY\",\r\n  \"Speaker\":\"Female1\",\r\n  \"Format\":\"mp3/32/m\",\r\n  \"Quality\":\"quality/normal\"\r\n}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://url/CloudService/ReadText")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "0a1ce7c9-7a95-a2b9-7cde-8a7e6ce58386")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

But when I use the above code in android it fails, I'm sure that I got Internet permission and the code is executed within an `AsyncTask`.

I'm not asking about the API or how to send `json` `Post` request to some API and get a binary file in response. I've used `client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback(){//stuff here});` but none works. In response I got a 307 status code (instead of 200 in `Postman`) and no binary data at all. The API is very unclear and said nothing about the failure and I'm still working on that.

**All I'm asking** is that does `Postman` generates equivalent code for `OkHttp` correctly? and if not what is your suggestion for equivalent of this request in `Java/OkHttp`?

Just to provide another example, the following is also a working `Python` `requests` script to do the same job:

```
url = 'http://url/CloudService/ReadText'
api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'
body = {
    'Text': 'Hello',
    'Speaker': 'Female1',
    'Format': 'mp3/32/m',
    'Quality': 'quality/normal',
    'APIKey': api_key
}
header = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=header)
```

Answer (score 1):

So after 3 days I found the problem, the server API did not mention that the `URL` endpoint must be ended with an `/` and even in their sample code they didn't use one.

It seems that both `Postman` and Python `requests` use an `/` at the end of `URL` in case of need, but `Postman` at least does not mention that in the generated equivalent code. Also `OkHttp` does not operate in the same manner.

However using a trailing `/` solved the problem.